# How to access HTML element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Silly question but i am new to javascript.i am trying to access html element by Id=*mySelect*.but getting console error.

```js
$(function() {

  var count = 0;

  $("#btn").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    debugger;
    AddOptions("mySelect", count, "Hello");
    count++;
  });

  function AddOptions(SourceName, value, Title) {
    debugger;
    var objResolve = $("'#" + SourceName + "'"); //here getting console error "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '#mySelect'"
    objResolve.append("<option value='" + count + "'>Cate Male</option>");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect"></select>
<input type="button" id="btn" title="Add" value="Add" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
$("'#" + SourceName + "'");
```

to

```
$("#" + SourceName);
```

```js
$(function() {

  var count = 0;

  $("#btn").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    AddOptions("mySelect", count, "Hello");

    count++;
  });


  function AddOptions(SourceName, value, Title) {
    var objResolve = $("#" + SourceName); //here getting console error "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '#mySelect'"
    objResolve.append("<option value='" + count + "'>Cate Male</option>");

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect"></select>
<input type="button" id="btn" title="Add" value="Add" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't put `'` characters in the selector. You use those for JavaScript string literals.

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
var objResolve = $("'#" + SourceName + "'");
```

to

```
var objResolve = $("#" + SourceName);
```

No need for extra quotes at the beginning or the end